# SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT interaction with Update query for Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, locking

I'm currently using `SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` on a table to prevent multiple threads from executing the same query. At the same time that is being executed, another thread might be running `UPDATE` queries on some rows the same table.

What is the exact interaction between these two queries? Will the `UPDATE` query return with an exception or will they block until the `SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` is done?

Comment: DBMS is Oracle 11g. The rows are identified by UUIDs. Sorry for the misinformation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT, any other concurrent select for updates or updates whose candidate set match at-least one of the same rows will need  to wait until the row-level lock is released or undefinitiely.

If you use another select for update instead of update, you can use nowait or skip locked clauses to modify this default behaviour.

Comment: And vice versa? Meaning the select for update will block if there was a concurrent update on the rows selected?

Comment: Yes, the select for update will block any concurrent update. The update statement does not have options like nowait or skip locked as "select for update" has.

Comment: Sorry for the poor phrasing. I meant if it's in the middle of updating the rows (update query came first), will the select for update query be blocked or throw an exception when accessing the rows being updated?

Comment: The select for update will be blocked. You can use nowait  but the select will end immediately without raise any exception. If you use "skip locked" instead you will lock only a subset of rows.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to find a workaround for that issue since I need to use "nowait"